# Laravel API versioning folders structure

Tags: php, laravel, api, api-versioning

I am new in api versioning ,so my question is :

1)Is this folder structure true?

```
/app
  /controllers
    /Api
      /v1
        /UserController.php
      /v2
        /UserController.php
```

for routes :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
  Route::get('user',      'Api\v1\UserController@index');
  Route::get('user/{id}', 'Api\v1\UserController@show');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'v2'], function () {
  Route::get('user',      'Api\v2\UserController@index');
  Route::get('user/{id}', 'Api\v2\UserController@show');
});
```

2)what about folder structure for models and events , should I make model for every version?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your approach is correct for API versioning. To avoid repeating the `Api\vN\` prefix before every controller path, you could also do:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\v1'], function () {
  Route::get('user',      'UserController@index');
  Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v2', 'namespace' => 'Api\v2'], function () {
  Route::get('user',      'UserController@index');
  Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');
});
```

Also don't forget to change your controller's namespace. For example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\v1;
```

If you don't want to manage it by yourself you could also use some API library that supports versioning. I successfully used [Dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api) many times but probably there are some more available.

I don't think you should version models. They should represent your current database structure and therefore be unique. If you need to make some changes, try to make it backwards-compatible with the API versions you are still maintaining.

Same story for the events, unless they are strongly coupled to your API. In that case, I believe that the best folder structure should be equivalent to the controllers one:

```
/app
  /Events
    /Api
      /v1
        /ApiEvent.php
      /v2
        /ApiEvent.php
    GenericEvent.php
```